# oidc-client popup window as new tab in browser instead

Tags: oidc-client-js

Attempting to implement OidcClient.signinPopup() but have it open in a tab.

In the UserManagerSettings I've set popupWindowFeatures property to null but it continues to open as window rather than new tab in chrome.